# EF6 Interceptor to set a value on Insert or Update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am having troubles trying to figure out how to use the EF6 interceptors to set a value on Insert/Update.

What I wanted to do is to have an interceptor to automatically create a new instance of `Audit` like so:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Audit AuditAndConcurrencyKey { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Invoice Header { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //For legacy reasons. I know this design is wrong :(
    public Audit AuditAndConcurrencyKey { get; set; }
}

public class Audit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InstanceId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void WillCreateAudit()
{
    using (var db = new FooContext())
    {
        var inv = new Invoice {Name = "Foo Invoice"};
        var invLine = new InvoiceItem {Header = inv, Price = 1, Name = "Apple"};
        db.Invoices.Add(inv);
        db.SaveChanges();


        //Inceptors should figure out that we are working with "Invoice" and "InvoiceLine"
        //And automatically create an "Audit" instance
        Assert.That(inv.AuditAndConcurrencyKey != null);
        Assert.That(invLine.AuditAndConcurrencyKey != null);
        Assert.That(inv.AuditAndConcurrencyKey == invLine.AuditAndConcurrencyKey)
    }
}
```

The first thing I checked is [this example](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=) for `SoftDeleteInterceptor`. I don't think this is what I want because it looks like at the point where we are already generating the expression tree, we are no longer aware of the type of object you are working with.

I checked [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) as well, but again, it looks like we are injecting strings instead of setting object references.

Ideally I want something like this:

```
public class AuditInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Invoice) && !(obj is InvoiceItem))
            return; //not type we are looking for, by-pass

        //Set the audit here
    }
}
```